# Read file from one remote location and upload it to another remote location in ruby

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an URL http://mydomain.com/abc.mp3 from where I want to copy the audio file and want to upload it on another URL http://another_doamin.com/abc.mp3

Anyone can suggest me to do this in ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have FTP access for another_domain.com?

Comment: Permission is not an issue. I'v the permission.

Comment: What protocols are available? Is it HTTP file upload?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, depending a lot on what are the capabilities of your applications (servers). You might want to be a little more precise in your question. Here are some that spring to my mind when thinking about "reading file from one location and uploading it to another":

1. Use FTP. Either directly from one domain to another (if one of them has FTP server and you have shell access to the other), or through a third machine (download with http and upload with ftp, assuming that *another domain* has FTP server). [Here is some documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/index.html) you may find useful, it includes an example. This is probably the simplest and most straightforward option.
2. Submit the file through HTML form, assuming that something (like Rails app or even PHP script) can handle such request at *another domain*. You can do that with HTTP, as [documented here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html), with examples, and [answered in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423209/post-file-using-rubys-http-class).
3. Use forwarding from an address in *another domain* to an address in *my domain*, assuming you have control over app running at *another domain*. This is more [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org) than Ruby. It will not make your file transferred from one domain to another, instead it will redirect calls from one address to the other.
4. Obtain (with 1., 2., `wget`...) the file from *my domain* while generating page on *another domain*, assuming as in 3. Once again, this is more Rails than pure Ruby. This will obtain a copy of a file from one domain to another whenever requested.

Comment: Or another option: You could base64 encode the file and send it over a web service.

Comment: I want to know how can you upload a file at remote location in ruby :)

Comment: @Ashish: to upload a file "somewhere" means that "somewhere" must accept such operation. If it accepts FTP, use FTP. If it accepts HTTP POST requests, use HTTP POST requests (updated my answer to contain a link to a related question). If it accepts HTTP GET requests, base64 encode the file and use HTTP GET requests (pass the encoded string as a parameter). It is impossible to tell *how* to do it without knowing what are the allowed ways of uploading.

Comment: I have HTTP access, so want to do it using NET-HTTP or open URI ruby libraries:-)